# How do I dock a pidgin window in X?

Tags: linux, window-manager, x-windows, pidgin, dock

Using the Windows Pidgin Options plugin, I can make the buddy list be dockable.  If I dock it, other windows avoid it when maximising themselves.  How do I do the same thing in X?

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/5220) out.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your window manager. For example, Fluxbox has no such feature, while wmii is a tiled window manager that organizes windows in columns and keeps windows from overlapping in most circumstances.

Comment: that is more a lack of feature on the side of pidgin, fluxbox supports so called "struts" (some panels provide them) where the app tells the windowmanager to reserce a certain area on the screen where maximized windows are kept away from ...

Comment: @akiraL I don't think the Pidgin developers see their buddy list as a panel. (It's pretty wide.) If they did, they would have designed it differently, to pop out or something.

Comment: they can see it as what they want, if they want the wm to not maximize windows over it they have to tell the wm its a "panel".

Comment: @akira: they don't see it as a panel, therefore they decided not to tell the wm that it's a panel. If you want the WM to see it as a panel, then you have to patch pidgin.

Answer (score -3):

never heard about [AllTray](http://alltray.trausch.us/about.php)?

Take a look.

Comment: I hadn't; thanks for pointing it out.  I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for; I'm interested in docking a window to the edge of the screen, rather than hiding it in a system tray.  Pidgin already displays a notification area icon anyway.